# Could not add new columns to model

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using PostegreSQL.
What I've tryed already:

```
python manage.py flush
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations app
python manage.py migrate app
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

There aren't any effect. The table have no recently added columns.
Have no importaint data in tables, can remove it.

Comment: Does these commands throw you an output (like _applying app.XXX... OK_)? Also check if you're looking/pointing at the intended database.

Comment: @JordanM., no, there was not such outputs. Prior to this, all models worked fine.

Comment: did you check that your app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @JordanM., the question is already solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all migration files (except the **init**.py files) and database, rerun makemigrations and migrate.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all DB tables.
2. Remove all migration files from migrations directory.
3. python manage.py makemigrations
4. python manage.py migrate

Comment: When I run migrate have LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMA...

Comment: And have you empty database?

Comment: No. But now it doesn't matter :) I've dropped this table and trying to create new

Comment: @PavelAntspovich You need empty database for initial migration.